# Can we change method signature in overriding?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

As i know, in overriding we can't change the signature of the method. If will try to change, it will through a Compile time error.

So can anyone help me to understand why i am not getting error in below code.
[image]

Comment: No. That would be overloading.

Comment: Add code as text not as image

Comment: @ernest_k Can you please explain ? As far as i know that is overriding and if i will change the method signature it should through CTE.

Comment: @DeepakMalav What makes you say it's overriding? What's do you understand as difference between overriding and overloading?

Comment: @DeepakMalav you are not overiding but you create a second, additional method in the child with a different signature. So in Child both methods exist next to each other - without conflict as their signatures differ. Therefore this is perfectly valid.

Comment: @kai Can we change method signature in overriding ?

Comment: no you can't. As you don't override but create an additional method that coexists everything is perfectly fine.

Comment: @kai if i change the method signature in sub class method then will it become overloading?

Comment: yes multiple methods with the same name but different parameters are called "overloaded". But overloading is not overriding.

Comment: @kai  overloading is happening in same class but here classes are different.

Comment: Overloading is happening in the same class(both methods are there next to each other): the child. But whoever claims that it may not be called overloading if inherited methods are involved, should come up with a better name. Never heard such claim and I'd say it's impossible to uphold as you may not know the whole derivation tree(e.g. in a lib). So: Its overloading.

Answer (score 1):

Because you changed the parameter type your example is showing overloading, not overriding.

You can add the [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation to guard against accidental mistake like that:

```
@Override
public void testMethod(float b) {

}
```

will cause a compilation error.